# onWindowResize event parameters using Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am making my first steps coding with javascript and also playing with Three.js.

The thing is that I always see this function to can reduce my scene proportionally when I reduce the width and the height of my browser's screen:

```
function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}
```

I made this: http://codepen.io/gnazoa/pen/BjoBZz and that is using the same `onWindowResize()` function.

Now my question is: Is there a way to decide how much I want to reduce my 3d object when the browser window reduce too?

I tried to write this `object.scale.set -=1.5;` inside the  `onWindowResize()` function and it doesn't work, then I searched in the threejs.org examples and I dont find anything. Do you have some suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring you `var object` inside your `function init()`. It' won't be accessible from `function onWindowResize()`.
To make it work it has to be a global variable as your `camera, scene, renderer`, etc.

Then in your `function onWindowResize()` try:

```
object.scale.multiplyScalar(1.5);
```

or:

```
object.scale.set(1.5, 1.5, 1.5);
```

Comment: Thank you @leota, but even if I declare var object as a global variable it doesnt make what I want. The thing is that I want to decide how much to reduce my object when the screen size reduce, so like this it could be visible in a mobile device.

Comment: For the moment it reduce his size when I reduce the height of my screen, but it stays with the same size when I reduce the width of my screen.

Comment: @ValentinVerdegales answer updated. Remember to remove "var object" inside your init(). Leave just "object", as it's been already declared as global var

Comment: Thank you @leota but now I can only see my object dessapear while he becomes smaller.

Comment: @ValentinVerdegales - Check new update. Anyway you now have a link between you onWindowResize() and your object.scale, so play a bit with it to achieve what you need

Comment: Thank you it helps me a lot